# Center mouse button to move between worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, mouse

I have an excel workbook with about 30 worksheets. I know I can do Ctrl+PageUp and Ctrl+PageDown to move between the worksheets.

Is there a way to do this using the center button on my mouse as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any shortcut in Excel to do it. If you've got [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com), you could use the following script to do it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+*Mouse Scroll*):

```
#IfWinActive, Microsoft Excel ; Makes the hotkey work only when you're working in a window titled Microsoft Excel
^+WheelDown::Send ^{PgDn} ; Control-Shift-Scroll Down moves to the next worksheet
^+WheelUp::Send ^{PgUp} ; Control-Shift-Scroll Up moves to the previous worksheet
#IfWinActive ; End of hotkeys that only work in Excel
```

**Even better,** you could use this version of the script to change worksheets when you're scrolling and holding down the right mouse button (so you only have to use one hand!):

```
#IfWinActive, Microsoft Excel ; Makes the hotkey work only when you're working in a window titled Microsoft Excel
RButton & WheelDown::Send ^{PgDn} ; Right Mouse Button-Scroll Down moves to the next worksheet
RButton & WheelUp::Send ^{PgUp} ; Right Mouse Button-Scroll Up moves to the previous worksheet
RButton::Send {RButton}
#IfWinActive ; End of hotkeys that only work in Excel
```

This approach prevents you from right-dragging in Excel, but I haven't seen any special result from doing that.